# Define validation on all controller routes

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Let's say I create Admin Controller that includes all refers to administration pages.
In each controller i do validation that the user is admin and other validations,
Its look like my code repeats itself and i want to make local event on enter any route in admin controller and do these validations, I know i can declare one function that do these validations but again I must need to set her on any method in AdminController.

Thanks for helpers.

Example of admin controller method:

```
public IActionResult References()
{
    var user = Systems.Users.GetUser(HttpContext);
    if (Systems.Users.IsValid(user) && 
        Systems.Users.IsPermission(user, Models.User.EUPermissions.Admin))
            return View();
    return View("Error404");
}
```

Comment: Use `[Authorize]` attribute and role based authentication to allow/disallow access to your resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following in Startup.cs `ConfigureServices()` method:

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("AdminAccess", policy => policy.RequireRole("Admin"));
});
```

Now in your controller, you can use the following:

```
[Authorize(Policy = "AdminAccess")]
public class AdministratorController : Controller
{
  public IActionResult Index()
  {
    return View();
  }
}
```

This way, you don't have to write code for checking access. .Net core promotes dependency injection and other solid principles and you don't have write methods which are doing more than one responsibility.